# Saving Data in a recursive function to a list

Tags: java, list, algorithm, recursion, arraylist

I'm working on a function which breaks down the given input into denominations using a recursive call.

At each step it recurses into two variants:

1. Continue with the current coin: Add it to the list and recurse.
2. Switch to the next coin: Increment coin pos and recurse.

In addition to printing out the combination of denominations captured in the list when remaining == 0, I intend to capture the value of that list and return it from the function.

Here's the code:

```
    static final int[] DENOMINATIONS = {9,5,3};

    private static void change(int remaining, List<Integer> coins, int pos)

        if (remaining == 0) {

       // This correctly prints the desired output. 
       // I want to return that exact value from the function.
            System.out.println(coins); 

        } else {
            if (remaining >= DENOMINATIONS[pos]) {
                coins.add(DENOMINATIONS[pos]);
                another.addAll(coins);
                change(remaining - DENOMINATIONS[pos], coins, pos);
                coins.remove(coins.size() - 1);
            }
            if (pos + 1 < DENOMINATIONS.length) {
                change(remaining, coins, pos + 1);
            }
        }
    }


    public static List<Integer> denominations(int amount) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> another = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        change(amount, result, another ,0);
        System.out.println(another.size());
        return another;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = denominations(13);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
```

Output : [5, 5, 3]

Comment: Is this based on the SICP counting-change example?

Comment: I suppose it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems to assume that java is passed by reference which is not true. Java methods are passed by value.

I have updated your code:

change method:

```
private static List<Integer> change(int remaining, List<Integer> coins, int pos) { // Updated method return type;

    if (pos < 0 || pos >= DENOMINATIONS.length) { // check if position is invalid
        return new ArrayList<>(); // return an empty list
    }

    if (remaining == DENOMINATIONS[pos]) { // check if remaining is equal to denominations[pos]
        coins.add(DENOMINATIONS[pos]); // add the denominations to the coins result
        return coins; // return the result
    } else if (remaining > DENOMINATIONS[pos]) { // check if remaining is greater than denominations[pos]
        coins.add(DENOMINATIONS[pos]);// add the possible denominations to the coins result
        remaining = remaining - DENOMINATIONS[pos]; // calculate the new remaining
        if (remaining >= DENOMINATIONS[pos]) { // check if remaining is greater than or equal to denominations[pos]
            return change(remaining, coins, pos); // stick to this position
        } else {
            return change(remaining, coins, pos + 1); // increment pos to go to the lower denominations
        }
    } else if (remaining < DENOMINATIONS[pos]) { // check if remaining is lesser than denominations[pos]
        if (coins.isEmpty()) { // if coins is empty then go to the next denomination
            return change(remaining, coins, pos + 1);
        } else {
            coins.remove(coins.size() - 1); // remove the previous denomination
            return change(remaining + DENOMINATIONS[pos - 1], coins, pos); // go back to the previous remaining and // try this DENOMINATIONS[pos]
        }
    }
    return coins;
}
```

denominations method:

```
public static List<Integer> denominations(int amount) {
    return change(amount, new ArrayList<Integer>(), 0);
}
```

**INPUT** : `13`
**OUTPUT** : `[5, 5, 3]`

Comment: Thank you Mark. It works well. I would highly appreciate if you could briefly explain the need for denominations method here. I'm trying to understand the underlying concepts.

Comment: I just tried to fit my solutions to your solution. The denominations method is not needed. You can simply call the change method into your main method.

Comment: The functions returns an empty list for some input values like 21 , 30 . Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to add `return coins;` at the and of `change` method, but you can keep it the way you have it. Returning and changing an array is a code smell as the method both operates on object (modifies it) and returns a result.

To make it work, you can define your `denomination` method as follows:

```
public static List<Integer> denominations(int amount) {
   List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   change(amount, result, 0);
   return result;
}
```

Edit:

The list is empty because the only place it's changed is here:

```
coins.add(DENOMINATIONS[pos]);
change(remaining - DENOMINATIONS[pos], coins, pos);
coins.remove(coins.size() - 1);
```

Where an element is added and removed. It's what you have written that makes it empty:)

Edit2:

I would suggest passing around a second object, that would be a copy of the list you would like to return and is not modified.

Comment: I've tried that but it still returns an empty list. I modified my code according to your suggestions

Comment: Yes you're right . And that because the items are being removed from the list. It's the value of list i want to return exactly when if(remaining == 0). Where modifications do you suggest?

Comment: I have added a suggestion;)

Answer (score 1):

`change` should return boolean that mean whether has been found an answer.

So `change` body looks like this:

```
if (remaining == 0) {
  return true;
}
...
if (change(...)) return true;
...
return false;  // It's last line of body
```